# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first_name')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call a component (authors) which iterates through an array using MAP when I click the component but I keep getting type errors, can anyone see where I'm going wrong.

[consolelog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di9YJ.png)

[data returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTgl6.png)

[image: Error picture]

I have four components

- paper.js
- papers.js
- authors.js
- author.js

the papers component fetches a list of papers from my API then displays to the screen like so:

[image: example]

When a paper is clicked I want to display a list of authors and this is where I run into the error.

Paper.js

```
import React from "react";
import Authors from "./author";


class Paper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            display: false
        }
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({display:!this.state.display})
    }

    render() {
        let details ="";
        if (this.state.display){
            details = 
            <div>
                
                <p>{this.props.paper.abstract}</p>
                <Authors />
                
            </div>
        } 
        return ( 
            <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                <p>{this.props.paper.title}</p>
                {details}
            </div>
         );
    }
}
 
export default Paper;
```

papers.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from './paper';

class Papers extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { results : [] } // declaring state
        console.log("constructor");
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        let url = "http://localhost/api/papers";

        if (this.props.author_id !== undefined){
            url += "?authorid=" + this.props.author_id;
        }
 

        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json() 
              } else {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
              }
            
        })
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({results:data})
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("something went wrong", err)
        })
        console.log("mounted")
    }
    render() {
        console.log("render");
        console.log(this.state.results);
        return (
            
            <div>
                {this.state.results.map( (paper, i) => (<Paper key={i} paper={paper}/>) )}
            </div>
                
        )
    }
}
 
export default Papers;
```

authors.js

```
import React from "react";
import Papers from "./papers.js";


class Author extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            display: false
        }
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({display:!this.state.display})
    }

    render() {
        let details = "";

        if (this.state.display){
            details =
            <div>
                <Papers author_id={this.props.author.author_id} />
            </div>
        } 
        return ( 
            <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                <p>{this.props.author.first_name + ' ' + this.props.author.last_name}</p>
                {details}
            </div>
         );
    }
}
 
export default Author;
```

authors.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Author from './author';


class Authors extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { results : [] } // declaring state
        console.log("constructor");
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        let url = "http://localhost/api/authors";

        

        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json() 
              } else {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
              }
        })
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({results:data})
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("something went wrong", err)
        })
        console.log("mounted")
    }
    render() {
        console.log("render");
        console.log(this.state.results);
        return (
            
            <div>
                {this.state.results.map( (author, i) => (<Author key={i} author={author}/>) )}
            </div>
                
        )
    }
}
 
export default Authors;
```

Comment: the first time the component renders `authors` is undefined. check that it exists before trying to access any of its keys

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot with the result of `fetch(url)` data from your url?

Comment: that's a lot of code, but obviously this.props.author is undefined.

Comment: I've uploaded an image of the data returned by both components